# SPRING XD: Is there a way to upload modules "automatically"?

Tags: spring, bash, spring-xd

Is there a way to upload modules using something like a script?

For example, we have a lot of modules, and is not a pleasure to upload modules, one by one every time a new version of our modules is ready to be used.

Comment: Can you share the exact commands you use to upload the modules?

Comment: I'm using the regular way to upload modules in Spring XD through the shell:

´module upload --some_name --type source --file "c:\\folder\\some_module.jar" ´

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the REST API, especially the section dedicated to modules:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#module-definitions

/modules/{type}/{name}
POST
upload a module archive (uber jar), where The content type is application/octect-stream and the request body contains the binary archive contents

Answer (score 0):

I use a combo of jenkins and shell script for this.  Jenkins checks out the code and deploys to the admin node.  Jenkins then runs a script on the admin node that contains the 'module upload....' command.  If you're running in a cluster, you can use jenkins to run a script for scp/rsync/cp your jobs folder to each of the other nodes (not needed if you're using hdfs or NAS mount).

I'm able to use this to deploy to multiple environments and also deploy versioned modules.....via parameterization.